# Create empid automatically following particular pattern

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've created an employee table which is having following columns:

```
id ||  empId || name || companyCode  
==    ======    ====    =========
```

I want emplId to be automatically created.

**Option1:** 
Every employee should get unique id.
EmpId should starts with companyCode.

Suppose company code is 'ci', then its employee id should starts with ci like ci101, ci102....

Is there any way to do it like creating some sequence etc.?
Note: I'm using mySql.
Expected output:

```
 id ||  empId || name || companyCode  
    ==    ======    ====    =========
    1       ci101     abc       ci
    2       xi101     xyz       xi
    3       ci102     lkj       ci
```

**Option 2:**
Id of every company employee should start with 100. Like first employee of X, Y or Z company should start with 101 as shown below:

```
 id ||  empId || name || companyCode  
    ==    ======    ====    =========
    1       101     abc       ci
    2       101     xyz       xi
    3       102     lkj       ci
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a trigger which updates the inserted row's empid based on company code and id, hope this helps

```
CREATE TRIGGER empid 
AFTER INSERT ON 'employeeTbl' for each row
begin
    UPDATE `employeeTbl` SET `empId ` = CONCAT(NEW.companyCode, NEW.id) where id=New.id; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the options you suggest, because arbitrary IDs shouldn't carry any meaning.  According to normal forms, the fact that an ID is an employee id or that an employee is employed by a company should be ascertained from the database, not from the ID's value.

The simplest way to generate your employee id is by adding 1 to the highest one:

```
insert into employees
select 1 + max(id) as new_id, ... values ... 
from employees
```